# Visualized shapes of areas of total and partial solar eclipse

Tags: solar-eclipse, resource-request, education, map, 2d-animation

I'm looking for an animated (showing how the situation changes as time passes) online map of a solar eclipse (can be a past or future one, it's for educational purposes) showing areas on Earth with total and partial eclipse. I prefer that the animation doesn't leave traces of past shapes of those areas, just what they are at the moment, not to obscure the picture. And a possibility to rewind to any timestamp, stop and resume animation. Do you know any good resources?

Neither Google Search, nor AI finds any (not even without animation). IIRC, there used to be many in the 90s and 00s, but nowadays they seem not to make them anymore (probably not to scare off an average user by something he's less likely to understand).

Comment: There are lots of eclipse animations on Fred Espenak's https://eclipsewise.com/eclipse.html but not quite what you're asking for. There's a *huge* amount of detailed eclipse data on that site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are purpose-made animations for recent eclipses on the NASA pages: [2021 Annular Solar Eclipse](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4910/). You can download the video, and with a decent player like vlc, you can thus go back and forth. You can find a similar animation for every eclipse on [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/).

Noteworthy and very impressive is this NOAA page where they created an animation from weather satellite data showing the path of the solar shadow across Earth in real images: [Solar Eclipses: Shadows from Space](https://www.nesdis.noaa.gov/our-environment/optical-phenomena/solar-eclipses-shadows-space).

I couldn't verify whether it really covered every eclipse, but this helped me: https://www.nasa.gov/?search=eclipse